# Should down votes be peer reviewed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I wonder if people sometimes use the down vote subjectively (and unnecessarily).

Looking at [the explanation page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), and specifically:

> **When should I vote down?**
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

it made me think about [a post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25029785/3650944) that was recently downvoted (curiously after selecting an answer, after making edits and reaching what I thought was a fairly good question).

In the very least, I can't say it was *an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post*, especially not after revising tags, formatting and grammar for clarity, so I was wondering, could peer reviewing down votes make SO a better place?

Comment: I sense this post has been perceived as egregiously sloppy. Feedback would be nice.

Comment: no, let me have my anonymous downvotes so i can downvote for reasons unknown to you

Comment: Nah. [We just don't think what you're asking for is necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Peer review? A feature request triggered by *one* downvote on a positively-voted question? Needs better reasons.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Cheers. It also has the discussion tag, so if there is any merit discussing the actual question, by all means.

Comment: There's not much to discuss. It's clear that it would be a waste of time to implement what you've asked for, and it goes against the entire point of voting. It sounds like you're focusing too much on the down votes you received rather than performing an honest self evaluation of why you got down voted. If the down vote still seems way out of place then ignore it. It hardly affects your reputation.

Comment: @mason There isn't much to go on to actually perform a self evaluation. The documentation however has to be considered ambiguous. It might as well be changed to "when should I vote down? Whenever you feel like it."

Comment: It is a human system. People are not robots and sometimes act irrationally. Shrug and move on.

Comment: @mason Alright. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: The voting system is inherently peer reviewed - all of the votes are merged between disagreeing reviewers to produce one final score.

Comment: "I wonder if people sometimes use the *up vote* subjectively (and unnecessarily). Should *up votes* be peer reviewed?"

Comment: If there is a down vote it should at least come with a comment with a reason.  If that is not provided assume the person voting is an idiot and move on.  you will earn the rep back on your next answer.

Comment: @BradLarson I thought up voting was much more encouraged than down voting (and I personally think it should be).

Comment: @AdamJensen - Downvotes are merely counterparts to upvotes. In order to vote for high-quality or correct posts, we must also be able to vote for low-quality or incorrect posts. Neither is preferred, they are simply opposite sides of the same coin.

Comment: @BradLarson Then why is it discouraged in help? Why do you lose rep for downvoting?

Answer (score 4):

**Why were you downvoted (once)?**

Being the first person to comment on that post :P. I think you were downvoted because the downvoter thought that your benchmarking criteria / strategy wasn't correct. Check *Alfasin's* comment / answer on the post (provide warm-up runs..).
 Also. like I mention in my comment the first time you do `s = "";`, `""` will be added to the String pool. Such details might seem *trivial*, but are important nevertheless. Maybe the downvoter thought that you had not put in much effort in knowing how to properly analyze such situations..

PS :On a personal note, I disagree (this doesn't mean he/she is wrong) with the downvoter. the question seems to be legitimate (and good). But then again, people have the right to vote / downvote.

Comment: `But then again, people have the right to vote / downvote` anonymously.

Comment: @gnuanu I like the anonymity, but I don't think it is very constructive. And while everyone has a right not to be constructive, I definitely don't think it should be as easy as it is right now to potentially do passive-aggressive damage. Perhaps if there was something like anonymous reviewing; optimally with anonymous feedback/reasoning.

Comment: @gnuanu - I agree.. People have the right to downvote without providing proper reason for the same.

Comment: @gnuanu I don't think voting anonymously should be the character of this community.  The point is that this is a community to educate others.  Anonymously down voting without any comment as to why provides no educational value and there for is pointless.